# LINK2019: unresolved external symbol for a function returning shared_ptr<int>

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, visual-studio-2013, shared-ptr

I am using a dll exporting a function that returns a shared_ptr.

The code from the dll project:

```
#ifdef _WRAPPER
    #define WRAPPER_DLL_EXT __declspec(dllexport)
#else
    #define WRAPPER_DLL_EXT __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


std::shared_ptr<int> WRAPPER_DLL_EXT func()
{
    return std::make_shared<int>(5);
}
```

The code from the project using the dll:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> myPointer = func();
```

I get error `LINK2019: unresolved external symbol` for `func()`.

The dll project is compiled using **Visual Studio 2013 Toolset**, whereas the project using the dll is using **Visual Studio 2010 Toolset**.

Compiling the dll using VS2010 toolset prevents the error, but I am using VS2013 features in the implementation so I cannot actually compile the dll with VS2010.
Note that I cannot upgrade the using project to VS2013.

How can I make it work **using VS2013 toolset** for the project using the dll?

Edit: it works if I change `shared_ptr` to `unique_ptr` (but, of course, it's not what I need).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

use pure-C API for your dll ***OR*** use the same toolset versions for the DLL and the executable

**Long answer:**

C++ is not [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface)-compatible across different compiler versions. This means that different versions of toolsets will not produce compatible binaries. C++ names can be mangled differently, memory layout is different etc – this will either lead to the linker not being able to find the right functions, or some dire runtime errors. The only way to be sure stuff is ABI-compatible is to use a language that is guaranteed to be ABI-stable between toolset versions, and that is C.

This is basically the reason why Windows APIs that are exposed through DLLs are C functions with plain C structures and stuff.

[Some more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/440161/dll-compatibility-between-compilers) on StackOverflow.